# Not able to bind data in master page

Tags: sapui5

i'm not getting any results when i try to display json data in the master page.It just displays no data whereas when i do the same thing in the main view i'm able to display the data.

Here is my code :

Mview.view.xml

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" displayBlock="true"
controllerName="com.firstproject.FirstProject.controller.Mview" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="Master Page">
    <content>
        <List id="UserList" items="{users>/Users}" headerText="Users">
            <items>
                <ObjectListItem title="{users>name}"/>
            </items>
        </List>
    </content>
</Page>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>FirstProject</title>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-preload="sync"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
        data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
        data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"com.firstproject.FirstProject": "./"}'>
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

    <script>
        var app = new sap.m.SplitApp({initialPage:"idMasterPage1"});
        var mpage = sap.ui.view({id:"idMasterPage1", viewName:"com.firstproject.FirstProject.view.Mview",type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
        var dpage = sap.ui.view({id:"idDetailPage1", viewName:"com.firstproject.FirstProject.view.Dview",type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
        app.addMasterPage(mpage);
        app.addDetailPage(dpage);
        app.placeAt("content")
    </script>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
```

manifest.json

```
"models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "com.firstproject.FirstProject.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "users":{
            "type":"sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel",
            "uri":"model/listdata.json"
        }
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Also i'm getting this error with or without any list in the master view

```
Assertion failed: ManagedObject.apply: encountered unknown setting 'initialPage' for class 'sap.m.SplitApp' (value:'idMasterPage1')
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute initialPage is no longer usable as an attribute for the sap.m.SplitApp control. Instead you can use initialMaster association to avoid this message.

var app = new sap.m.SplitApp({initialMaster :"idMasterPage1"});

Answer (score 0):

The entire `manifest.json` is not evaluated because it's not being loaded at all. Start from [OpenUI5 walkthrough](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/3da5f4be63264db99f2e5b04c5e853db) and review your code by comparing it with specifically the steps "Component Configuration" and "Descriptor for Applications".